# yaml-cpp cmake error, boost files not found

Tags: yaml-cpp

I just downloaded and tried to build yaml-cpp v. 0.5.1, did everything as specified both in the web page and in the install.txt file, but got the following error: `CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1138 (message):Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.`

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Downloaded version 0.3 instead and it built just fine.

Comment: Do you have boost installed?

Comment: Just installed boost and it works fine. Thanks!